# Android Studio: what does the green dot mean in the "Run" button?

Tags: android-studio

What does the green dot that sometimes appear inside the `Run` button mean, exactly?

[image: green dot inside Run button]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Android Studio is based on Intellij IDEA.

Quote from Intellij IDEA:

> Now every run configuration has a small green indicator that tells you
>   if it’s running.

This green circle indicates that the selected run configuration is now running. Try stopping it, and see the green circle disappear.

[IntelliJ IDEA 15 EAP Adds Indication for Running Configurations](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/08/intellij-idea-15-eap-adds-indication-for-running-configurations/)

Answer (score 1):

Run with Green dot icon was replaced by another one

[image] -> [image]

But the idea is the same - app is running and when you press it, the previous app will be exited and new app will be created